# Why do I see cookies I did not set?

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-11, mixpanel

I occasionally receive warnings from PHPIDS about certain cookies, and on further examination, it appears that a particular client keeps sending me cookies that I did not set, e.g. mp_d21cb8a9f34838c02aeec897b3728a94_mixpanel.

How is that possible? It was my understanding that cookies are only sent back to the server/domain that set it, and I do not use mixpanel and to my knowledge did not set that cookie.

I understand that mixpanel is a web tracking tool, but I do not use it (I use Google Analytics). I have no other users on my server/domain, I have no affiliate ads/banners on my site, and I do not support user generated content. So I am fairly certain that my server did not set that cookie, but then why does the client browser (IE11) keep sending me that cookie? The user's behavior seems legitimate, i.e. it appears to be no bot or script.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding how cookies work? Can some other server set cookies for MY domain? Any ideas how this comes about? Are there known browser bugs that mixes up cookies?

Regards,

Arno

Comment: Other servers can't set cookies for your domain, but JavaScript code running on your domain could. Maybe the visitor has a browser plugin that uses Mixpanel and unintentionally set the cookie for your domain? Or it's a developer testing something in the console? Did you buy a domain Mixpanel was used on previously?

Comment: So a Browser plugin could set a cookie for my domain? That might explain it. At least it is something to look for. The domain is a German language domain that certainly was not used before. I am the only developer right now, so that is also out. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yeah client-side code like browser-plugins can set cookies for your website. Anyone who comes to your website can also set cookie's through the console. (That's what I meant by a developer testing something - maybe they just happened to have your website open when they tried to see if some Mixpanel code runs correctly.)